# How do capture parameter in URL on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an encrypted URL slug and it's displaying like this `http://localhost/pending/$2y$10$r3N01R19/M4UURceDSNGkuEInQ1LQC5OvBoEiugYOhpla8f3wHZU2`.

Now, how do I get the only encrypted slug `$2y$10$r3N01R19/M4UURceDSNGkuEInQ1LQC5OvBoEiugYOhpla8f3wHZU2`, in Laravel controller and dump?

**Controller**

```
public function pending(Request $request, $enc_code)
{
    $slug = $request->get($enc_code);
    dd($slug);
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/pending/{enc_code}', 'PagesController@pending')->name('page.pending');
```

Comment: Should this sort of route setup not pass the value into your controller as `$enc_code` already?

Comment: @CBroe I have realized there is a slash `/` in encrypted slug  which assumes there is another slug in URL, now how  do I hash variable and omit slash `/`

Comment: if you try `dd($enc_code);` it should show your slug

Comment: You don’t have control over what result these hash functions produce. Properly URL-encode the value, before you insert it into the URL context, so that any / will become %2F instead.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I have got solution, I used `str_replace ('/', '', Hash::make($request->get('enc_code')));` to remove forward and it works.

Comment: That doesn’t sound like a solution, it is likely to _invalidate_ the hash value, so you won’t be able to verify it afterwards (which I’d assume will be done later on, otherwise what would be the purpose of using any hash in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

May be it could be help in your case.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
Request::segment(count(Request::segments()))
```

Answer (score 0):

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;
>
> ....
>
> Request::segment(count(Request::segments()))